# Need help with an integration word problem. This appears to be unsolvable due to lack of information.

Tags: calculus, integration, problem-solving

I'm not sure I understand what to do with what's given to me to solve this. I know it has to do with the relationship between velocity, acceleration and time.

> At a distance of $45m$ from a traffic light, a car traveling $15 m/sec$ is brought to a stop at a constant deceleration.
>
> a. What is the value of deceleration?
>
> b. How far has the car moved when its speed has been reduced to $3m/sec$?
>
> c. How many seconds would the car take to come to a full stop?

Can somebody give me some hints as to where I should start? All I know from reading this is that $v_0=15m$, and I have no idea what to do with the $45m$ distance. I can't tell if it starts to slow down when it gets to $45m$ from the light, or stops $45m$ from the light.

---

Edit:

I do know that since accelleration is the change in velocity over a change in time, $V(t)=\int a\ dt=at+C$, where $C=v_0$. Also, $S(t)=\int v_{0}+at\ dt=s_0+v_0t+\frac{1}{2}at^2$. But I don't see a time variable to plug in to get the answers I need... or am I missing something?

Comment: What you are "missing" is that you are not given a time, t, because that is what you are asked to **find**!  Yes, the velocity after time t is $v_0+ at= 15- 3t$.   You are asked to find the time until the velocity 3 m/s.  So solve 15- 3t= 3.  Yes, the distance traveled will be $v_0t+ (1/2)at^2= 15t- (3/2)t^2$.  You are asked to find the time to travel 45 m so you need to solve $15t- (3/2)t^2= 45$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  Constant acceleration means that the velocity $v(t)=v(0)+at$ where $a$ is the acceleration.  The position is then $s(t)=s(0)+v(0)t+\frac 12 at^2$.  You should be able to use these to answer the questions.

Comment: I wasn't thinking properly when I labeled this question as physics. Yes, it's a physics type question, but this is a calculus class, and I'm asked to do this as an exercise in integration. I do know though, that since accelleration is the change in velocity over a change in time, so $\int a\ dt = at+c$, where $c=v_{0}$. Also, $\int v_{0}+at\ dt = s_{0} + v_{0}t + \frac{at^{2}}{2}$. But I don't see a time variable to plug in to get the answers I need... or am I missing something?

Comment: @agent154:  To find the time when the velocity is zero, use the velocity equation.  Set $v(t)=0$ to get $t=\frac {-v_0}a$, then put this into the $s$ equation.  You want $s(t)=45$, which will let you find $a,t$

Answer (score 2):

The question is poorly formulated, but I imagine the intention is that the car is 45m from the traffic light and moving directly toward the traffic light when it begins to decelerate, and that it decelerates just enough to stop exactly at the traffic light.  That seems to be enough information to lead to a unique solution, using what you already know.

Comment: Indeed, that did help. I wouldn't be surprised if that's what the professor meant, seeing as he's foreign. Thanks for the insight.